# AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 4, 43, 24, 206775, tzinfo=<UTC>) != '2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I run tests.py for tests, so I got an error

```
self.assertEqual(self.user1.regist_date, '2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533')
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 4, 43, 24, 206775, tzinfo=<UTC>) != '2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533'
```

I wrote in tests.py like

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import User

# Create your tests here.
class UserModelTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user1 = User.objects.create(name='Tom', regist_date = '2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533',age=20)

    def test_user1_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.name, 'Tom')

    def test_user1_regist_date(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.regist_date, '2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533')

    def test_user1_age(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.age, 20)
```

models.py is

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=True)
```

I thought type of regist_date is datetime.datetime not string, so I rewrote
setUp of tests.py is `self.user1 = User.objects.create(name='Tom', regist_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 4, 43, 24, 206775, tzinfo=<UTC>),age=20)`,so Can't assign to function call error happens.What is wrong in y method?How can I fix this?

Traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/uu121291/recomin/app/tests.py", line 17, in test_user1_regist_date
    self.assertEqual(self.user1.regist_date, datetime.strptime('2017-09-20 06:03:48.570498', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 6, 7, 49, 51089, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 6, 3, 48, 570498)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 18 tests in 0.076s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: What value do you have in `regist_date`? Will be better if you convert str `'2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533'` to `datetime` object

Comment: @AndMar regist_date's type is DateTimeField.I think if I use str type, can't I resist time I resist data in db?What do u mean in ur message?

Comment: I mean to convert str date `'2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533'` which you are using in test `self.assertEqual(self.user1.regist_date, '2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533')` to python datetime

Comment: @AndMar I can understand ur message meaning.But I cannot understand where should I convert datetime  DateTimeField into  str?Could u write in answer or message ur intended codes?

Comment: `self.assertEqual(self.user1.regist_date, datetime.strptime('2017-09-19 08:47:51.807533', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))`

Comment: @AndMar I wrote `self.assertEqual(self.user1.regist_date, datetime.strptime('2017-09-20 06:03:48.570498', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))` and run the file, so I got an error `self.assertEqual(self.user1.regist_date, datetime.strptime('2017-09-20 06:03:48.570498', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 6, 7, 49, 51089, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 6, 3, 48, 570498)` .What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you add traceback to your question?

Comment: @AndMar I added traceback in y question

Comment: It happened because time in DB and in test function is different. `7, 49, 51089` not equal to `7, 49, 51089`. For passing this test you should use `self.assertNotEqual`